# bulletin-board database design

Tags: database, database-design

suppose I needed to design a database for a bulltin-board website.
something like stackoverflow which means there is a topic and a series of posts
**but, no threaded posts (not a tree-based design)**

I thought about two main options:

1. Topic table and Post table. Post has "topic_id" field
2. no Topic table. only one big Post table.

what do you think is the more preferable option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, stackoverflow is a tagged based design, where a post may have multiple topics/tags.

So to capture this in a relational-style design, you would have three tables:

1. POST (post_id, author, etc.)
2. TOPIC  (topic_id, name, etc.)
3. POSTTOPIC (post_id, topic_id)

The reason for POSTTOPIC is because a post may have multiple tags.  Using #3, it becomes easy to assign/unassign tags to a post or to find posts with certain topics.  None of which a column in POST would be able to accommodate.

Comment: This creates a  Many-to-Many  relationship  between Post and Topic. So it can allow a Post to be used for more than one Topic, unless some form of constraint is added to prevent that.  It would be more usual to  have  a 1-to-Many relationship between Topic to Post. To support Tags, add a separate Tags table with a PostTag table to create a Many-to-Many relationship  between Tag and Post.

Comment: I believe is treating tag and topic as equivalent.